# I need to print Google Sheet list in the console as comma delimited line

Tags: c#, .net, list, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am accessing the Google Sheet and would like to bring each record of it to the Console output as comma delimited data (last_name, first_name, id .. etc.).

The amount of data elements in the list that is created is unknown, so I would like to replace the code with the one that is dynamically finds the amount of elements (columns) in the list row.

My code below (commented out) - does not work - shows all single elements in one column.

```
ValueRange response = request.Execute();
IList < IList < Object >> values = response.Values;
if (values != null && values.Count > 0) {
    foreach(var row in values) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
        Console.WriteLine(row.Count);
    }

    ///foreach (var row in values)

    //{

    // for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    //{

    //Console.WriteLine(row[i]); 
    //}

    //}
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing this? This isn't App Script code so I'm not sure how you're accessing the Sheet.

Comment: Please provide proper tags including the language you're using to access the api

Comment: Could you use the `Files: export()` method of the Drive API? You can export a sheet to CSV format using the `text/csv` MIME Type and then read the values in from there?

Comment: I am using C# Do you think the full code would be helpfull?

Comment: @Ross Yes, could link the full code and a publicly viewable copy of the sheet structure with all sensitive data removed?

Comment: I am using the template found here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

You can do this generically by using the foreach loop and print each entry on the same line using a spacing of `', '` if not the last cell in that row:

```
foreach (var row in values){
    var length = 0;
    foreach (var cell in row){
        Console.Write($"{cell}");
        length++;

        if (length < row.Count){
            Console.Write(", ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```